# Should I worry about dynamic codegen mismatch with my other modules written in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a Proto file which is being used in a NodeJs and C++.

C++ is using protoc compiler whereas NodeJS is using dynamic codegen, My worry is that if the C++ uses a different compiler version than my NodeJS dynamic codegen, could it be an issue for us?

If yes, What do you guys recommend to resolve this? Should I use static codegen? What are the advantages and disadvantages for both If anyone can help me understand, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a problem with using those two different protobuf/gRPC code generation methods together. The different code generation methods affect the API, but they are still working with the same serialized format, so they can send messages to each other without problems. In fact, gRPC has a continuous interoperability test suite to ensure that these different clients and servers can communicate with each other.

One potential issue to keep in mind is [a bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/8999) with the way the current Node.js gRPC dynamic codegen handles repeated primitive fields. To avoid this problem, you should explicitly set the `packed` attribute on any repeated primitive field.